# Eclipse Juno JSP syntax highlighting doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I installed the Java EE version of Juno and opened an existing project I'm working on. First thing I noticed was that there was no syntax highlighting on my JSP's. I checked my install and I do have WTP installed.

Any ideas why this isn't working? It has worked out-of-the-box on every other version of Eclipse that I've used.

Comment: Right-click on your JSP file and go to the "Open With..." menu.  Are you sure you're actually using the JSP Editor?

Comment: JSP editor is not there. Shouldn't it be there just like previous versions of Eclipse?

Comment: How did you install this Java EE version of Juno?  Did you accidentally install the non-EE Java package?

Comment: I checked that before I posted. The only thing I can think of that could be causing the problem would be that I'm using JDK 1.5 because I'm working on with an old version of ATG. I'll try installing at least 1.6 and see if that clears it up.

Comment: Someone else has reported the same issue with Juno. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385028

Comment: In which we learned that yes, you do need Java 6.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Same problem happen to occur for me. I had tried this solution and it worked for me.

1. Check your `JDK` must be `1.6` or later. If not install `JDK 1.7`
2. If problem still persists, In *Eclipse* Go to `Help -> Install New Software -> WorkWith (Select Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno)` -> Expand   `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development -> Web Page Editor` (Check it) and install it.

   Restart eclipse after installing. Now open a existing jsp file with `Web Page Editor`.
   To do this right click on jsp file `open with -> Web Page Editor`. If `Web Page Editor` is not present go to `Other -> Internal Editors -> Web Page Editor`
   **Or**
   Go to new file create with .jsp extension and open with web page editor

   Now in *Eclipse* Goto `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations`
   Select *.jsp and make web page editor as default editor
3. Create a shotcut for *Eclipse *on desktop and right click on shortcut go to `properties->shortcut tab -> target`

   In the target add these line in braces (`-vm "path` for your bin folder of jdk 7")
   For Example target should look like 
   `"C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin"`

Comment: I had the same problem. I followed only step 2. Done! Thanks

Comment: Step 2 is all I needed, FYI: I had only downloaded the eclipse SDK package, none of J2EE stuff.

Comment: For "Eclipse Luna" Web Page Editor is "JSF Tools - Web Page Editor".