# Java Server Pages and Google App Engine

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

I'm running a Google App Engine with Endpoints. Everything works fine. Now I would like to add some JSP's for admin purposes. So, following the docs, I added a JSP in /war/.

Works, too. But I don't have any syntax highlighting (Eclipse) and when there's a code error, I get the following compilation error. But without syntax highlighting, it's no easy to locate the error. Any idea?

> Failed to compile the generated JSP java files

Comment: you have some code example?  from what I see... you can't compile.  Not super clear how to help you compile though....  Are you asking to fix that specific code error or to find a way to have syntax highlighted for your jsps?

Comment: If I provide I code sample, I would need to ask again and again while programming. So the problem is not the code itself, it's why Eclipse is not highlighting the JSP code or why Google does not exactly say in which line the error is.

Comment: yeah debugging with the app engine is not super fun honestly. I think you will have to maybe look for a Jsp plugin and try to see if that solves your issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324201/eclipse-juno-jsp-syntax-highlighting-doesnt-work  might solve your problem)

Comment: which one?  so we can create a real answer for your question :P will be clearer than looking in docs

Comment: Done. Next time, post your comment as an answer and you will earn the reputation.

Comment: I wasn't sure which one would've been an answer, and I honestly don't bother that much with rep :).   I have enough to help people and it's enough for now ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Eclipse installation was the ADT Bundle. Therefore web-editors where not included by default. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324201/eclipse-juno-jsp-syntax-highlighting-doesnt-work), I installed the missing plugins. Works now.